# The texture blurs when the window size changes

Tags: directx11

When i change window size to big size, texture becomes blurred. 
When window is small, texture is normal.

[image]

Anisotropic filter is used.

With point filter

[image]

Without mipmaps.

Back buffer == desktop window size.

I rebuild text and icon when Windows send window message when resize.

Rebuild is simple - remove old, create new (with new coordinates).

Simple rendering

```
    m_d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout( ((ShaderImpl*)shader)->m_vLayout );
    m_d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader( ((ShaderImpl*)shader)->m_vShader, 0, 0 );
    m_d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader( ((ShaderImpl*)shader)->m_pShader, 0, 0 );
    m_d3d11DevCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

    m_d3d11DevCon->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &d3dm->m_vBuffers[ i ], &stride, &offset );
    m_d3d11DevCon->IASetIndexBuffer( d3dm->m_iBuffers[ i ], DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

    if( shaderD3D11->m_callback )
        shaderD3D11->m_callback->onShader( *material, m_shaderProcessing.data() );

    if( material->flags & (u32)MaterialFlag::AlphaBlend )
        enableBlending( true, material->alphaToCoverage );
    else
        enableBlending( false );

    if( material->flags & (u32)MaterialFlag::Backface ){
        if( material->flags & (u32)MaterialFlag::Wireframe )
            m_d3d11DevCon->RSSetState( m_RasterizerWireframeNoBackFaceCulling );
        else
            m_d3d11DevCon->RSSetState( m_RasterizerSolidNoBackFaceCulling );
    }else{
        if( material->flags & (u32)MaterialFlag::Wireframe )
            m_d3d11DevCon->RSSetState( m_RasterizerWireframe );
        else
            m_d3d11DevCon->RSSetState( m_RasterizerSolid );
    }
    m_d3d11DevCon->DrawIndexed( d3dm->m_subs[ i ].iCount, 0, 0 );
```

Texture creation

```
bool TextureD3D11::init( Image* image ){

if( !image ) return false;

bool is_RTT = (image->frames == -1);

if( !is_RTT )
    image->convert( ImageFormat::R8G8B8A8 );

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory( &desc, sizeof( desc ) );
desc.Width  =   image->width;
desc.Height =   image->height;
desc.Format =   DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count   =   1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality =   0;
desc.BindFlags  =   D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
desc.MiscFlags  =   is_RTT ? 0u : D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;
desc.ArraySize  =   1;
desc.MipLevels  =   1;
desc.Usage  =   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc.CPUAccessFlags =   0;

ID3D11Texture2D * texture = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = 0;

if( is_RTT ){
    hr = m_gs->getD3DDevice()->CreateTexture2D( &desc, NULL, &texture );
    if( FAILED( hr ) ){
        LogWriter::printWarning( u"Can't create render target texture" );
        return false;
    }
    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
    renderTargetViewDesc.Format = desc.Format;
    renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    hr = m_gs->getD3DDevice()->CreateRenderTargetView(texture, &renderTargetViewDesc, &m_RTV);
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        LogWriter::printWarning( u"Can't create render target view" );
        return false;
    }
}else{
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    ZeroMemory( &initData, sizeof( initData ) );
    initData.pSysMem     =  image->data;
    initData.SysMemPitch =  image->pitch;
    initData.SysMemSlicePitch = image->dataSize;
    hr = m_gs->getD3DDevice()->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &initData, &texture );
    if( FAILED( hr ) ){
        LogWriter::printWarning( u"Can't create 2D texture" );
        return false;
    }
}

m_texture = texture;

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc;
ZeroMemory( &SRVDesc, sizeof( SRVDesc ) );
SRVDesc.Format = desc.Format;
SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
SRVDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip   =   0;
SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = is_RTT ? 1 : -1;

hr = m_gs->getD3DDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView( m_texture,
        &SRVDesc, &this->m_textureResView );
if( FAILED( hr ) ){
    LogWriter::printWarning( u"Can't create shader resource view" );
    return false;
}

if( !is_RTT ){
    hr = this->createSamplerState( (D3D11_FILTER)m_gs->getParams().m_textureFilterType, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP, 16u );
    if( FAILED( hr ) ){
        LogWriter::printWarning( u"Can't create sampler state" );
        return false;
    }
}

m_size.x = image->width;
m_size.y = image->height;

return true;
}
```

Shader

```
Texture2D tex2d_1;
SamplerState tex2D_sampler_1;

cbuffer cbPixel{
    float4 diffuseColor;
    int isAlphaDiscard;
    int isGradient;
    int reserved[2];
};

struct VSIn{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
};

struct VSOut{
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
};

struct PSOut{
    float4 color : SV_Target;
};

VSOut VSMain(VSIn input)
{
    VSOut output;
    output.pos   = input.position;
    output.uv    = input.uv;
    output.color = input.color;

    return output;
}



PSOut PSMain(VSOut input)
{
    PSOut output;

    float4 txcolor = tex2d_1.Sample(tex2D_sampler_1, input.uv) * float4( diffuseColor.r, diffuseColor.g, diffuseColor.b, 1.f);

    if( isAlphaDiscard ){
        if( txcolor.a < 0.5f ){
            discard;
        }
        txcolor.a = diffuseColor.a;
    }else{
        txcolor.a *= 1.f - diffuseColor.a;
    }

    output.color = txcolor;

    if( isGradient ){
        output.color += input.color;
        output.color.a *= 1.f - diffuseColor.a;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Texture coords for chars

```
template<typename rectType>
void uvRectToUV( const rectType& rect, v2f * LT, v2f * RT, v2f * LB, v2f * RB, Texture * texture ){
    f32 mulX = 1.f / (f32)texture->getWidth();
    f32 mulY = 1.f / (f32)texture->getHeight();

    v2f lt, rb;
    lt.x = rect.x * mulX;
    lt.y = rect.y * mulY;
    rb.x = rect.z * mulX;
    rb.y = rect.w * mulY;

    *RB = rb;
    *LT = lt;

    LB->x = lt.x;
    LB->y = rb.y;

    RT->x = rb.x;
    RT->y = lt.y;
}
```

Comment: I don't know direcx or anything, but you literally provided no code or anything. Nobody can help you...

Comment: @Joza100 I think the code is not needed. Who have experience will understand.

Comment: no man.... If you make a mistake in the code that makes something go wrong, then people need to see the code to see the mistake, but you provide no code so nobody can help you...

Comment: Anisotropic filtering isn't really suited to the case you're showing. Since it looks like you just want a straight 1:1 blit from the icon texels to the screen pixels, point filtering would be a more conventional choice. Anisotropic filtering helps when you're looking at something tilted or squashed, where one axis is compressed more than the other.

Comment: You might want to upload your examples in a lossless format like png. The jpeg compression artifacts make it difficult to identify what you're seeing on your screen versus what's just compression errors.